# PHP Best way to get to compare to assoc arrays and create a new one with matchings

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

image we have 2 assocs arrays:

## 1

```
array 
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '1' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '5' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '7' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '8' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '12' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '13' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum'
```

## 2

```
array 
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '2' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '5' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '7' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '58' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '66' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '78' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum'
```

What would be the best way to create a new array, that have all entries that matches at 'id'? So basically like doing a sql query with an INNER JOIN on 2 tables that would contain this data.

The result should look like this:

```
array 
  0 =>
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '5' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' 
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'id' => string '7' 
      public 'desc' => string 'Lorem Ipsum'
```

I was trying around a bit, but doing an array map with checking for each object if there is an equivalent in the other array seems not to be the best solution for this.

thanks

Comment: Use [`array_uintersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php). Or, if possible, use the value of property `id` as key when you create the arrays and then use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(
    (object) array(
        'id' => '4',
        'desc' => 'Four'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'id' => '5',
        'desc' => 'Five'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'id' => '3',
        'desc' => 'Three'
    )
);

$arr2 = array(
    (object) array(
        'id' => '2',
        'desc' => 'Two'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'id' => '4',
        'desc' => 'Four'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'id' => '6',
        'desc' => 'Six'
    )
);

$arr3 = array();
foreach( $arr1 as $obj1 ){
    foreach( $arr2 as $obj2 ){
        if( $obj1->id == $obj2->id ){
            $arr3[] = $obj1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $arr3 );
echo '</pre>';
```